# How To Pronounce "IFRS"?

Tags: pronunciation, terminology

How to pronounce "IFRS," International Financial Reporting Standards?
Anybody knows its phonetic symbols with IPA symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In American English is pronounced /aɪ ɛf ɑr ɛs/; in British English is pronounced /ʌɪ ɛf ɑː ɛs/.

Comment: But if it's run together, as in Neil's answer, the 'r' will be sounded between vowels even in non-rhotic accents.

Answer (score 0):

You pronounce it as initials, so in phonetic transcription of typical British English I'd suggest e.g. [ɑjɛfɑɹɛs].